Como hago para tomar el valor del jwt en el sessionStorage usando cypress?
Estoy intentando automatizar el login de una url de prueba, donde necesito tomar el valor del jwt para luego poder reutilizarlo para hacer validaciones varias
El codigo que estoy usando es:
   beforeEach("Precondicon", () => {
        cy.visit("urldeprueba")
        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            // returning false here prevents Cypress
            // inside the cy.origin() method from failing the test
            return false
        })
    
        cy.get("[name='usuario']").type("138")
        cy.get("[name='clave']").type("2233")
        cy.get("[type='submit']").click()
    
        cy.window().then((win) => {
            cy.wait(8000);
            cy.log(win.sessionStorage)
            cy.log(win.sessionStorage.jwt)
            cy.log(win.sessionStorage.getItem("jwt"))
            
            for (let i = 0; i < win.sessionStorage.lenght; i++) {
                const key = win.sessionStorage.key(i);
                const value = win.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
                cy.log(key)
                cy.log(value)
    
            }
        })
    })

Tanto en el cy.log del for como en el de win.sessionStorage directo, veo que aparece el jwt, pero no tengo forma de poder tomar el contenido.
Intente de formas varias con sessionStorage.getItem("jwt") pero no hay manera
Edit:
En el
for (let i = 0; i < win.sessionStorage.lenght; i++) {
            const key = win.sessionStorage.key(i);
            const value = win.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
            cy.log(key)
            cy.log(value)      
        }

me devuelve esto:
{
    "prueba": "eyJ123",
    "persist:userSession": "{\"_persist\":\"{\\\"version\\\":-1,\\\"rehydrated\\\":true}\"}",
    "ob": "true",
    "cargarPinpoint": "false",
    "csid": "1",
    "user": "true",
    "obState": "",
    "isServertime": "true",
    "tt_appInfo": "{\"platform\":\"pc\"}",
    "nombre": "Juan Perez",
    "chat": "true",
    "jwt": "eyJ123",
    "referer": "",
    "cdTabData": "{\"id\":\"1\",\"openTabTS\":172}"
}

En el cy.log(win):

sessionStorage: Storage
{
    "prueba": "eyJ123",
    "persist:userSession": "{\"_persist\":\"{\\\"version\\\":-1,\\\"rehydrated\\\":true}\"}",
    "ob": "true",
    "cargarPinpoint": "false",
    "csid": "1",
    "user": "true",
    "obState": "",
    "isServertime": "true",
    "tt_appInfo": "{\"platform\":\"pc\"}",
    "nombre": "Juan Perez",
    "chat": "true",
    "jwt": "eyJ123",
    "referer": "",
    "cdTabData": "{\"id\":\"1\",\"openTabTS\":172}"
}


Hola Poden, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganes tu primer medalla!. ¿Podrías explicar mejor cómo es que "veo que aparece el jwt, pero no tengo forma de poder tomar el contenido"? Si lo podes ver, no entiendo porque no lo podes usar

Hola, lo que quiero decir es que en la consola veo el contenido de todo el sessionStorage, pero necesito poder bajar a una variable el contenido en particular del jwt dentro del sessionStorage.
Intente con la función getItem pero siempre me devuelve null
let var = sessionStorage.getItem("jwt")
cy.log(var)
Por consola me devuelve null.
Pd: gracias por el consejo

¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar algo que nos indique cómo sabes que jwt está guardado en el sessionStorage? En el código compartido hasta el momento no hay nada que nos dé una pista de donde se guarda efectivamente.

Ahi edite la pregunta con las respuestas que veo

Es raro que el for sobre win.sessionStorage.lenght muestre ese resultado, porque deberían aparecer por el nombre de la clave seguido por su valor. Eso que mostras parece lo que debería ver al hacer cy.log(win.sessionStorage)

Podes probar acceder usando .its(), por ejemplo, así: cy.window().its("sessionStorage").invoke("getItem", "jwt").should("exist");

Con el comando  cy.window().its("sessionStorage").invoke("getItem", "jwt").should("exist");
Primero me muestra por consola its.sessionStorage y su contenido,
Siguiente linea invoke.getItem() con su contenido
Y por ultimo assert expected y el valor del jwt que necesito

Asunto solucionado:
cy.getAllSessionStorage().then((storage) => {
    const u = Object.keys(storage)[0]

    jwt = storage[u].jwt
    cy.log(jwt)


    let uthorization = `Bearer ${jwt}`
    cy.log(uthorization)
})


Asunto Solucionado:
cy.getAllSessionStorage().then((storage) => {
    
    const u = Object.keys(storage)[0]
    jwt = storage[u].jwt
    cy.log(jwt)


    let uthorization = `Bearer ${jwt}`
    cy.log(uthorization)
})

getAllSessionStorage trae todo lo que está almacenado en el sessionStorage, al hacer el object.keys sobre la variable de respuesta (storage) y ser la unica posicion del array, la puedo manejar de forma tal de poder tomar el valor requerido en la variable jwt.
Finalmente, armo el token armando una concatenación del tipo de auth requerida (bearer) con el valor de la variable jwt
